# Add number to listbox on button click C# ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Well, I have two buttons. One contains a + and one contains a -. Then I have a listbox where a number is displayed. If the user click the button with the + the number in the listbox should be increased by one. And if the user clicks - the number in the listbox should be decreased by one.

All of it should be done with binding because its a ViewModel.

This is my xaml Code:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="93,368,263,37"></TextBox>
    <Button Content="-" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="22" Margin="146,0,225,40" Command="{Binding sub}"/>
    <Button Content="+" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="22" Margin="180,0,190,40" Command="{Binding add}"/>
```

This is the C# code I have so far:

```
 public int quanitiy = 0;
    public ICommand add => new RelayCommand<string>(
        quanitiy = quanitiy + 1
        );
    public ICommand sub => new RelayCommand<string>(
        quanitiy = quanitiy - 1
       );
```

Comment: Why in a listbox instead of a textbox?

Comment: @KenTucker Textbox is also allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**XAML - View**
Not much change needed to the view, you just need to add in binding to show the value. I have also chnaged your command names because add is a C# keyword so don't want to use it here for the command name.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Quantity}" />
<Button Content="+" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" />
<Button Content="-" Command="{Binding SubtractCommand}" />
```

**ViewModel**
In order for this to work you need to have implemented RelayCommand and INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _quantity;
    public int Quantity
    {
        get => _quantity;
        set
        {
            if (_quantity == value) return;
            _quantity = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Quantity));
        }
    }

    public ICommand AddCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand SubtractCommand { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        AddCommand = new RelayCommand(param => Increase(), param => true);
        SubtractCommand = new RelayCommand(param => Decrease(), param => true);

    }

    private void Increase()
    {
        Quantity += 1;
    }

    private void Decrease()
    {
        Quantity -= 1;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Comment: I see you did not test the code because I cannot compile

Comment: @nivopo_10 I have updated my answer. Apologies there were some errors in the code I previously provided. For reference in order for this to work you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, RelayCommand and also set the view data context to the view model

Comment: @nivopo_10 In my answer I have also simplified some of the code you provided. For example in the increase and decrease methods I have simplified the addition and subtraction. This has all been tested and now works for your desired purpose.